# Variable width bars in ggplot2 barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a barplot with bar widths determined by an integer variable (sample size). Adding "width = variableName" doesn't seem to work. Is there an established way of doing this? Here's some dummy data and code. I want the bar widths to be a function of variable d in this example.

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c("A", "B", "C"), b=c(0.71, 0.94, 0.85), d=c(32, 99, 18))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=a)) +  
geom_bar(colour="black", size=.3) + 
theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about using `width=` after rescaling your `d` vector, say by a constant amount?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=a, y=b, width=d/100)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=a), stat="identity", position="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: @chi: that's great, thanks a lot. I'd already tried this approach, but without the 'stat' and 'position' arguments it didn't affect the bar widths.

Comment: Is it possible to add the width of the bars in the legend ?

Comment: THANK YOU! I was missing the position argument :)

Comment: how would you apply this to percent charts such the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984296/proportion-with-ggplot-geom-bar