# different width for each bar, using geom_bar with "position=fill" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

could you tell me if it is possible make a bar plot with bar height normalized to 1, but bar width proportional to the number of elements in each bin.

Example : this plot

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs))) + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

and then make the width of the 3 bars proportional to

```
table(factor(mtcars$cyl))
```

There is well that "width" parameter in position_fill() but it has to be a constant, hasn't it ?

Thank you,

François

EDIT :

I tried a bit further, and get the message : "position_fill requires constant width"

So I guess to get what I tried to get is impossible, at least using geom_bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948604/variable-width-bars-in-ggplot2-barplot-in-r

Comment: Well, that's more or less equivalent to generating a histogram plot with `hist` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can do it by preprocessing the data, but not entirely within a single `ggplot` call.

```
library("plyr")
mt <- ddply(mtcars, .(cyl, vs), summarise, n=length(cyl))
mt <- ddply(mt, .(cyl), mutate, nfrac = n/sum(n), width = sum(n))
mt$width <- mt$width / max(mt$width)
```

The `mt` data set now has everything needed to make the plot:

```
> mt
  cyl vs  n      nfrac     width
1   4  0  1 0.09090909 0.7857143
2   4  1 10 0.90909091 0.7857143
3   6  0  3 0.42857143 0.5000000
4   6  1  4 0.57142857 0.5000000
5   8  0 14 1.00000000 1.0000000
```

and the `ggplot` call would look like

```
ggplot(mt, aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs), y=nfrac)) +
  geom_bar(aes(width=width), position="stack", stat="identity")
```

It does throw the warning:

```
Warning message:
position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

but creates the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs))) + geom_bar(position="fill") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: No, what I was trying to do is presented in the post @Geek gave the link. I will try what they explained there. Thanks anyway for your answers.