# Proportion with ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the simplest way to do with ggplot the same as done here:

[image]

Do I need call prop.table or maybe there is a simplier way?

REPRODUCTABLE EXAMPLE:

```
x <- c("good", "good", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "perfect", "perfect", "perfect")
y <- c("exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3", "exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3", "exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3")
dt <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(dt, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a similar question to this previous one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100). You can use the `position = "fill"` argument within ggplot to scale bars to 100% height. The `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` command changes the frequency scale from 0-1 to 0-100%.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c("good", "good", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "perfect", "perfect", "perfect") 
y <- c("exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3", "exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3", "exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3") 
dt <- data.frame(x, y)

# Build plot
ggplot(dt, aes(x, fill = y)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: I've found that there is no need for use `table`... Al ya need to do is to add `position = "fill"` to the arguments of `geom_bar` :O

Comment: Good point: I was just adding more work for myself adding the frequency column and using the  `"stat = "identity"` argument. I have adjusted the code.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer your question without reproducible data, but generally you would want something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = YourData, aes(x = LevelNumVar, y = CountVar, fill = LevelLetterVar)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Where: LevelNumVar is your variable on the x-axis, LevelLetterVar is the variable you're shading on, and CountVar is your variable on the y-axis.

Here's the code using your data:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)

x <- c("good", "good", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "perfect", "perfect", "perfect") 
y <- c("exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3", "exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3", "exercise1", "exercise2", "exercise3") 
dt <- data.frame(x, y)

dt <- dt %>%    
  group_by(x, y) %>%    
  summarise(count = n())

ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = count, fill = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: I've added reproducible example.

Comment: the result is not as I wanted :( The barplot should be equal height. The result should be as in `barplot(table(dt))`