# ggplot2 histogram with different binwidth

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to use `ggplot2` to create a histogram with variable binwidths. I have integer values (JR) from 1 to 46 in different frequencies. I would like to create classes of 4 values each, i.e. 1-4, 5-8, etc.. The histogram should show 11 bars. The first 10 bars have the same width (4 values) and the last bar must be somewhat wider (6 values: 40-46).
With `geom_histogram` I can only creatz a histogram with equal bars. This works fine with `binwidth=2`, but this is too small. Better is `bindwith = 4`. But then the histogram starts with 2 on x-axis. It would help, when the x-Axis starts with 1.

```
ggplot(data, aes(JR)) + geom_histogram(aes(), binwidth=4)
```

Comment: please have a look around.. https://rpubs.com/rodolfo_mendes/change-number-bins-histogram

Comment: or for a solution using ggplot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948604/variable-width-bars-in-ggplot2-barplot-in-r

Comment: `geom_histogram` has a `breaks` argument. From the docs:
"Alternatively, you can supply a numeric vector giving the bin boundaries."

Comment: Oh, thats so easy. Thank you a lot for your help. Problem solved :-)